# Why VS2019 marks my extension as deprecated

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility

I don't use VSIX for integration (supports old VS and SSMS). Installer puts all dlls to "program files" and pkgdef and manifest to specific folders. Currently VS2019 shows message that my extension use "deprecated API".

Image with message from learn.microsoft.com but it's the same.

[image]

I done this steps:

- I created asyncPackage (now empty).
- Added  with
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor to vsixmanifest
- Generated catalog.json and manifest.json using code from [here](https://github.com/axodox/VsixUpdater)

My package looks so (constructor is empty now)

```cs
    [PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true, AllowsBackgroundLoading = true)]
    [InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "7.1.7", IconResourceID = 115)]
    [ProvideMenuResource("MyMenus.ctmenu", 1)]
    [ProvideAutoLoad(GuidList.ShellInitialized, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]
    [ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.NoSolution_string, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid(GuidList.guidMyPkgString)]
    public sealed class MyPackage : AsyncPackage {
```

But VisualStudio shows message about deprecated API again and again. What I missed? What VS checks during package loading?

**Edit**: I created AsyncPackage, added attributes, updated integration files to VsixV3. Why VS loads extension synchronously?

Comment: What message - please show!!

Comment: @ErikEJ added image with message. I have the same.

Comment: Did you clikc the "Learn more" link?

Comment: @ErikEJ it gets me to article ["Synchronously autoloaded extensions"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/synchronously-autoloaded-extensions?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Do you have a InitializeAsync method override?

Comment: Have you checked that it is your extension causing the message to appear?

Comment: @ErikEJ The same result with InitializeAsync and without. How and where I can check what causing this behavior?

Comment: Look at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/synchronously-autoloaded-extensions?view=vs-2019 (Performance Manager Dialog) !!

Comment: That is the question. If I created AsyncPackage and added attributes why VS loads synchronously?

Comment: Have you migrated your methods to Async methods?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Currently I don't use any methods, package is empty now.

Comment: Still struggling at this point since I can't reproduce your issue on my side. Like steps you share above, I can't figure out what's kind of your project. What function your extension works for? And as you mentioned above, it's a empty package, so how does your extension works, maybe that's the cause of the issue.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I found the issue. As I mentioned above we don't use VSIX. So pkgdef is coping by installer. I added `"AllowsBackgroundLoad"=dword:00000001
` to pkgdef.

Comment: Really glad to know you've solved it. And thanks for sharing your solution here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For whom this can help to resolve the same issue.
As I mentioned above we don't use VSIX. And all files are coping by installer. The issue was that this was missed:

```
[$RootKey$\Packages\{YOUR PACKAGE GUID}]
@="YOUR PACKAGE NAME"
"AllowsBackgroundLoad"=dword:00000001
```

I've found it during checking all packages in private registry `privateregistry.bin`

Also don't forget about `UI Context` if you are using it:

```
[$RootKey$\AutoLoadPackages\$UICONTEXT_GUID}]
"$YOUR_PACKAGE_GUID”= dword:00000002
```

Thanks to [MS git](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/blob/master/AsyncPackageMigration/NativeProjectSupport.md)